# Stuffit expander free on Mac OS 10.4.11

Tags: macos, mac, compression

Just two questions:

1. Does it exist?
2. Which version of stuffit expander is surely working on this version of mac os x?

I've been trying to download the 10.3 to 10.3.9 version from allume website but it won't install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last version of StuffIt Expander to work on 10.4 was 14.0.1 (StuffIt Expander 2010).  [This site](http://www.fileguru.com/StuffIt-Expander-For-Mac/download) claims to have a copy available for download, it seems to be pretty hard to find.

Comment: I do totally agree: that's a nasty one to find!

I'm downloading it right away: I'll keep you posted :)

Comment: Sorry for being a little late: the link is perfect :)

Comment: The link works perfectly as of today. Thanks for this.

Comment: Still working perfectly. Thanks - once again - a lot. :)

Comment: Unfortunately the link posted by afrazier no longer has version 14.0.1: try this instead
http://osx.iusethis.com/app/versions/stuffitexpander

Comment: File seems to be more and more rare.

Here's a new mirror:
http://mac.filehorse.com/download-stuffit-expander/945/

Comment: @Pitto I'm surprised anyone could still need this after nearly 7 years.  I'd have expected any remaining PowerPC users to have at least moved up to 10.5.

Comment: @afrazier let's not forget Bondi iMac lovers out there :)

Answer (score 2):

[The Unarchiver](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22774/the-unarchiver) is a great replacement for Stuffit Expander. It will work with Mac OS X 10.3.9 or greater, and is free.

Comment: The Unarchiver is great, but one thing it can't handle is JPEG images inside an SITX file.  This is a limitation listed on the developer's site.  There's probably some other edge cases it can't handle, but that's going to be the biggest stumbling block.  If the OP needs that, there's no way around it he or she needs StuffIt Expander.

Answer (score 0):

2018 here and the file keeps on disappearing from websites.

I've also [mirrored it too](http://www.davidenastri.it/files/expander_installer_en_116.dmg), in case someone needs it.